# Pegar tipo de conexão do usuário em javascript

Tags: javascript, conexão

como posso pegar o tipo de conexão do usuário em javascript? Quero saber se ele está acessando meu site via wireless, 4G, internet cabeada...

Tudo isso em javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar a **"Network Information API"** disponível em `navigator.connection`.

O suporte desta API ainda esta baixo e navegadores desktop (ou mobile) como Firefox, Safary e Edge ainda não a suportam outros suportam parcialmente alguns de seus recursos.

Entre algumas de suas opões você pode ter acesso a:

- **downloadlink**: representa a capacidade da taxa de download da conexão
- **rtt**: tempo médio de ida e volta de uma requisição (latência)
- **effectiveType**: 2g, 3g, 4, slow-2g (definido pela média **rtt** e **downloadlink**)
- **ConnectionType**: bluetooth, cellular, ethernet, mixed, none, other, unknow, wifi, wimax (tipo de conexão)
- **onchange**: função para monitorar mudanças na conexão

Você pode monitorar mudanças na conexão através de um **"handler"** ou mesmo observando o evento `change`:

```
function changeHandler(e) {
    //
}
navigator.connection.onchange = changeHandler;

navigator.connection.addEventListener('change', changeHandler);
```

**TESTE**:

```js
if ( navigator.connection ) {
    console.log(navigator.connection)
} else {
    console.log('Seu navegador não suporta a "Network Information API"')
}
```

Suporte [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#feat=netinfo)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[Link para a Especificação](http://wicg.github.io/netinfo/)

Answer (score 1):

```
navegator.connection()
```

Aqui está um breve resumo de utilização

```
if(navigator.connection) {
    if((navigator.connection.downlinkMax && navigator.connection.downlinkMax>1)
      || navigator.connection.type=='wifi') {
      document.body.classList.add('hifi');
    }
    else {
      document.body.classList.add('lofi');
    }
}
```

Agora um retorno da função

```
console.log(navegator.connection)
```

é similar a isso

```
NetworkInformationdownlink: 2.85
effectiveType: "4g"
onchange: null
rtt: 150
__proto__: NetworkInformation
```